# How to use 'this' pointer passed to a lambda as a function argument within a lambda?

Tags: visual-c++, lambda, std

I am using VS 2019 (C++20).

I can't compile a code where I am using std::visit with std::variant and function overload. The compiler reports an error "Function Visit does not take one argument". Obviously, the problem is with 'this' argument, but I could not figure out what is wrong.

```
class MyObj
{
public:
   void Visit(MyClass& arg) {};
};

void MyClass::Accept(std::variant<MyObj> arg)
{
   std::visit(
      overload{ 
            [=, this](MyObj& target) {target.Visit(*this);}
                  },  arg);
}
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Please provide a [mre], so we can copy-paste your code and compile it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with included header files. While VS IDE was fine, the compiler needed 'extern' declaration for the MyClass.